# Display Query String filter in page

Tags: sharepoint-server, query, sharepoint-list-filter

I have query string filter like:

```
Lists/DIIS/Master%20List.aspx?Modality=CT.
```

I would like to display `Modality=CT` somewhere on the page (not the title since I hide the title).

Is there a way to use javascript to display results of query on the page?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

You can show the query string on the page by adding Content editor/Script editor web part in your page.

You can get the query string parameters using javascript and bind those parameters in HTML. And provide the html file url on content editor web part.

**References**

1. [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-I-get-query-string-values-in-JavaScript).
2. [Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc).